# Create NSTextField to handle explicit newlines

Tags: swift, macos, text, appkit

I'm currently working on an appkit app that's based on a canvas in which a user can draw shapes and text. I'm trying to create a label that has the following characteristics:

1. When writing stuff inside it, its width adjusts automatically to its text content
2. **When pressing enter**, instead of ending the editing, **it should insert a newline**, adjusting the height respectively
3. For everything else, it should just behave like a regular `NSTextField`
   How can I go about that?

I tried replicating this behavior with `NSTextView` or `NSText`, but i'm stuck at this error, that you can reproduce with this MWE:

```
import AppKit

class MyView : NSView{
    
    
    let label = NSTextView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        
        label.backgroundColor = .blue
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        addSubview(label)
        
    }
    
}
```

using a custom view in storyboard and setting its class to `MyView`. Problem is that this doesn't seem the right approach for such a trivial task

Comment: Have you tried a delegate with `control(_:textView:doCommandBy:)`? How is the `NSTextView` code relevant for this question?